# flask - Unable to connect mogodb in heroku

Tags: python, mongodb, heroku, flask

I have an application using Flask and MongoEngine on heroku.

My configuration looks like this:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask.ext.mongoengine import MongoEngine

app = Flask(__name__)

#am setting proper configuration based on database uri
if os.environ.get('MONGOLAB_URI'):
    app.config.from_object(herokuConfig)
else:
    app.config.from_object(localConfig)

MongoEngine(app)
```

This was working fine up to yesterday, but this morning I am unable to run the application.

After looking into heroku debug logs, I observed **`AutoReconnect: not master`** error, but I am able to run it locally.

I have read some documentation regarding the above error occurring due to a `read_preference` setting.

I am unable to solve this, and am looking forward to suggestions.

Comment: Are you connecting to a replica set?

Comment: @dirn I Fixed that one by setting nwe MONGOLAB_URI in heroku config, but why that URL is changed in heroku any idea??